# If I have a metal instrument made of nickel titanium of length .001 m and very small diameter stuck, a tight tube, Can I apply a force using maglev?

Tags: electromagnetism

If I have a metal instrument (0.001m long and very small diameter) made of nickel titanium and stuck in a rigid tube, I need to exert magnetic force on this instrument using magnetic levitation concept.
i am thinking of approaching an AC electromagnet, that will induce eddy currents in the instrument(as it is made of an electrically conductive material), thus this Eddy current will produce magnetic field opposing the magnetic field of the AC electromagnet, can I get enough repulsive force to vibrate this instrument?

If i increase the strength of the electromagnet, can I get enough repulsive force to vibrate this instrument, if the electromagnet is 10 cm away from the instrument?

What if I dip the nickel titanium instrument in a liquid nitrogen, will the strength of the Eddy current increase thus the repulsive force will increase ?
what if i switch the nickel titanium with stainless steel ?

Answer (score 0):

$1$ mm is very small. Eddy currents will not flow significantly unless the frequency is very high. I doubt this approach will work. See Wire-grid polarizers on [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarizer) for a different example of how induced currents are important and size of the conductor matters.

You might think about heating or cooling the tube and instrument. Both will expand or contract with temperature. Which on changes more depends on the coefficients of expansion. If the tube has the larger coefficient, heat them. Otherwise cool them.

You might try a pressurized gas or liquid to push it out.